# Figuring out if javascript function has run already

Tags: jquery, function

I want to be able to trigger some code for after a div has loaded on the page from a script.

I have no access to the script, since it is loaded on the site from a 3rd party.

How do I fire a function after the 3rd party function runs?

e.g.

```
function threeParty(){
    //I have no access to this code
    $('body').append('<div id="testDiv"></div>');
}

function myFunction(){
     $('#testDiv').html("TEST");
}
```

I want to be able to do something like...

```
threePart.done(function(){
  myFunction();
});
```

or

```
$('#testDiv').load(function(){
  myFunction();
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you know *what* is being appended, you can keep checking if the item contains the appended HTML, until it does.

Comment: You could try to do something with [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), if you know where the div will be loaded.

Comment: I would prefer not to use an setInterval or setTimeout if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mutation observers are sweet. You can use one here. Basically, we add a listener to body. the listener reports back whenever nodes are added or removed. when that happens, check to see if our node was added. More info from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

```
//make the observer
var observer = new MutationObserver(
    //callback function, it gets triggered when anything mutates
    function (mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
            //see if the nodes mutated (something was appended)
            if (mutation.type === "childList") {
                //then the com changed. see if it has our element
                if ($('#testDiv').length > 0) {
                    //then the div was appended. do something!
                    myFunction();
                    //optionally, disconnect the observer if we're done listening
                    observer.disconnect();
                } //else, do nothing
            }
    });
});

//above, we made the observer. now, tell it to start observing `body`:
observer.observe(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0], {childList: true});
```

Note that I passed the argument `{childList:true}` to tell the observer we only care about changes to the body's child nodes, and not other changes such as changes to attributes.

Comment: That works perfectly! Thanks so much. I will have to learn more about this MutationObserver stuff. Seems very useful.

Comment: Just one more question, is there any other way of doing this that is compatible with lower versions of IE? Like IE9 and up?

Comment: the MDN for MutationObserver links to MutationEvents, the deprecated API that was replaced by MutationObserver. You use those like you would normal event listeners. They work in IE9+, but support is dodgy, the details of which I don't know off hand, you'd have to do trial and error https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events

Answer (score 0):

For those where IE isn't a requirement, you could use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to react to code completing in your JavaScript:

```js
$(function() {

  // Get info from 3rd party library (using moment.js as an example)
  function momentGetFromNow() {
    var m = moment(new Date(2016, 0, 1));
    var d = Date.now();

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      resolve(m.from(d));
    });
  }

  // Function to update UI after 3rd party Promise resolution
  function updateUI(value) {
    $("#test").text(value);
  }

  // momentGetFromNow returns a Promise object that we can react to
  var p = momentGetFromNow();

  // React to 3rd party function wrapper completion
  p.then(function(result) {
    updateUI(result);
  }).catch(function(reason) {
    console.log('moment.js call failed: ' + reason);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
```